# UI Controls not updating on using "Progress"

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have a web api request in a PCL which downloads the set of images in Base64 format from the server.

I have used Progress to track the bytes that's been downloaded and it's been given as the input to UIProgressView and some UILabels using a Listener.

Here I'm getting the values from PCL to my iOS project but it's not updating the UI. I believe UI is not updating because the main thread is blocked as the notification is getting delivered very fast.

Can any one suggest what's the best approach to update the UI?

P:S I'm updating UI in main thread.

```
    progressReporter.ProgressChanged += (s, args) =>
                {
                    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("args"+args.PercentComplete);
                        progressView.SetProgress(args.PercentComplete, true);
                        percentageLabel.Text = Convert.ToInt32(args.PercentComplete * 100).ToString();
                        totalPercentageLabel.Text = Convert.ToInt32(args.PercentComplete * 100) + " of 100%"; 
                    });
}
```

Comment: Do you get the "args..." Debug output?

Comment: Yep.. Im getting ...

Comment: I simulate the process that make the UIProgressView's Process increasing every second in the renderer and the event defined in Forms, it works fine. Did you run some code blocking the main thread in the Forms? (i.e. downloading?)